# jQuery reads the value but returns empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have function that reads the value of the text input and I just want to `console.log` that value to make sure it's working. But `console.log` returns just empty string. My Chrome developer tools shows no errors.
Here is the code:

```
<body>
   <input type="text" id="text-input" name="fname" placeholder="Last name">
   <button>Confirm</button>
</body>
<script>
    (function () {

        function searchFunction () {
            var stringValue = $('#text-input').val();
            $('button').on('click', function () {
                console.log(stringValue);
            });
        }

        searchFunction ();

    })();
</script>
```

Comment: fill out the input value and run again

Answer (score 4):

Of course it does... you set the value of `stringValue` at runtime - when the value is nothing, you never re-grab it on the click event:

```
function searchFunction () {
    var stringValue = $('#text-input').val();

    $('button').on('click', function () {
        stringValue = $('#text-input').val(); //RESET THE VARIABLE TO THE CURRENT VALUE
        console.log(stringValue);
    });
}

searchFunction ();
```